# ADF EO,VO,AM Implementation class

Tags: oracle-adf

What is the requirement of adf eo,vo and AM implementation classes???

when do we need this ??

can any one give some example on this?

i badly need these info.

Answer (score 1):

your question is so big!!

An eo,vo or am implementation class is used when you need some functionality that doesn't have  in the basic.

For example, in an implementation of view object. If you need to make an special query you can create your own method or overwrite the executeQuery method in order to get your goals. But, I must tell you that you should only do this if necessary. because most of the things you should be able to do the core of adf.

Other example that I use more times, is implement a VORowImp. This is very util when you must edit the attributes of Row, because using the implementation reduce the possibilities of error writting names and types.

Also, you can read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfinsider-093342.html

I hope help you.
Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with markosca, this is a big question to answer. It sounds like you're new to JDeveloper and ADF. I highly recommend going through the book“Quick Start Guide to Oracle Fusion Development: Oracle JDeveloper and Oracle ADF” [http://www.amazon.com/Quick-Start-Oracle-Fusion-Development/dp/0071744282](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071744282). It covers all of the basic areas of JDeveloper and ADF. Overall its a very well written book.

Or if you have the means, Oracle ADF classes level I and II are very good classes. I took these myself.

Please see the following link. I explain on the highlevel what the role is of using implementation classes on each Model Object type: http://pitss.com/us/2013/03/08/the-role-of-entity-object-view-object-and-application-module-implementation-classes/

I hope to write some code examples on the post above soon, but you probably won't see any code on there until a couple weeks from now.

I hope this helps!

Thank you,

Gavin Woods